# Como validar input file com jquery validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Estou tentando validar um `input` do tipo `file` com Jquery Validation.

Seguindo a documentação, faço o seguinte:
Meu input:

```
<input class="form-control" id="ImagemUpload" name="ImagemUpload" type="file" value="">
```

e meu script:

```
         $("#ImagemUpload").rules("add", {
                accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg",
                messages: {
                    accept: "Formato inválido."
                }
            });
```

Porém, não está validando e está aparecendo a seguinte mensagem no console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: Pode fazer um jsFiddle com o problema? Assim podemos testar e ajudar melhor. Há muitos plugins de validação. Dificil saber qual está a usar...

Comment: Estou usando http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estive a ler a documentação e não encontrei erro no seu código.

O que descobri é que é preciso um ficheiro extra para além do `jquery.validate.js` que encontrei [numa das demos do site](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/file_input.html).

É importante também lembrar que esse seu código tem de vir depois de ter iniciado o `.validate()`.

Fica uma demo a funcionar. Repare que precisa do jQuery, [jquery.validate.js](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js) e [additional-methods.js](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.js).

```
$('#form').validate();
$('#ImagemUpload').rules('add', {
    accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg",
    messages: {
        accept: "Formato inválido."
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pd08qtzL/

Comment: faltava o Additional-methods.js, não tinha reparado nisso no dia, obrigado